# Complexity of Identifying SAT Problems with a Unique Solution from Satisfiable Instances

Tags: np-hardness, sat, reductions, complexity

I am curious about the computational complexity involved in identifying SAT problems that have only one solution from a set of satisfiable SAT instances.

**input and output:** input: A satisfiable cnf formula. output: yes/no indicating if the given cnf formula has an unique solution.

**Background:** In the paper ["NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions,"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397586901350) it is stated that distinguishing between instances of SAT that have zero or one solution is as hard as SAT itself, under randomized reductions. Based on this, I am interested in understanding the complexity involved specifically in identifying uniquely solvable SAT problems from those that are merely satisfiable.

**Question:** What is the known computational complexity of identifying a SAT problem with exactly one solution from a set of SAT problems that are known to be satisfiable? Are there any established results or theories that describe this complexity?

Thank you for your insights!

Comment: What do you mean by "identifying"?  What is the input to the algorithm, and what is the desired output?  What is promised/guaranteed about the input?  (e.g., that at least one of the instances has exactly one solution?)

Comment: @D.W. input: a satisfiable cnf formula.  output: yes/no  indicting if the given cnf formula has a unique solution.

Comment: This is coNP-complete.  (Easy exercise.)

Comment: "I am interested in understanding the complexity involved specifically in identifying uniquely solvable SAT problems from those that are merely satisfiable." There is a complexity class, called US. It does not have a promise for the input formula being satisfiable, however, so is both NP- and coNP-hard.